# Postgres statement_timeout does not work as expected

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, timeout, locking, kill-process

I am working on a use case where in my current api application I need to kill any query that has been running more than 30 sec (as my server has a timeout of 30 sec but the query keeps running on Postgres).

So after some finding i came across the statement_timeout configuration in postgres. and implemented it in my sqlAlchemy code like this:

```
@contextmanager
def db_session():
    """Executes the query."""
    import os
    from my_aws import secretsmanager
    secret_name = f'<my_secrey_key>'
    secret = secretsmanager.get_secret(secret_name)
    conn = f'{secret["dbname"]}://{secret["username"]}:{secret["password"]}@' \
           f'{secret["host"]}:{secret["port"]}/{secret["dbname"]}'
    eng = create_engine(
        conn,
        connect_args={'options': '-c statement_timeout=30s'})
    connection = eng.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=eng))
    yield db_session
    db_session.close()
    connection.close()
```

So my expectation here was that any query whcih cannot complete within 30s should timeout and return an error.

So when testing this.

I place a lock in one of my tables to delay my queries by doing this:

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE <schema>.<table_name> IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE mode;
```

then i trigger an API call which queries the locked table (from above). this api does not repond as expected becuase the query is unable to execute witin 30 sec.

however the query does not terminate and i can still see it running in the `pg_stat_activity`

```
SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE query != '<IDLE>' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' and usename='api_user'
ORDER BY query_start desc;
```

So the above query gives the reponse:

```
pid |age            |usename |query                          
----|---------------|--------|-------------------------------
3334|00:05:17.962059|api_user|SELECT count(*) AS count_1 ¶FRO
1752|00:05:22.577919|api_user|COMMIT                         
1754|00:05:22.627446|api_user|COMMIT                         
3270|00:05:22.791417|api_user|SELECT count(*) AS count_1 ¶FRO
1755|00:05:23.058261|api_user|COMMIT                         
1753|00:05:23.123582|api_user|COMMIT                         
1689|00:05:24.149163|api_user|SELECT count(*) AS count_1 ¶FRO
1759|00:05:24.579171|api_user|SELECT DISTINCT sum(public.dema
1760|00:05:24.631371|api_user|SELECT count(*) AS count_1 ¶FRO
```

As you can see that the query on the locked tables are still waiting from more than 5 min.

Is there something wrong with my understanding of statement_timeout here.

FYI: I can see that the timeout is set on the postgres as the result of this query:

`show statement_timeout;`

Result:

```
statement_timeout|
-----------------|
30s              |
```

Comment: Is that `SHOW` command run from within sqlalchemy?  I ask because that ASCII-art looks to me more like a format I would expect from `psql` than from python.

Comment: Yes the show command is from psql.  I ran it on dbeaver.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you set the parameter in `postgresql.conf` (then it is valid for the whole PostgreSQL server) or with `ALTER DATABASE` (then it is valid only for new connections to that database).

If that does not do the trick, the setting must be overridden somewhere. To debug, run the following SQL statement using SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT current_setting('statement_timeout');
```

However, when I look at your query, perhaps everything is working anyway: add the `state` column to the `pg_stat_activity` query and check if the `state` is indeed `active`. Perhaps the query has already been canceled, and the state is `idle` or `idle in transaction (aborted)` (note that `query` shows the last query on that connection, which need not be active any more).

Answer (score 1):

I think The statement_timeout should be a value in milliseconds. If you are really passing in 30s, that might be the wrong parameter value. Try using 30000 for 30 seconds.

```
   eng = create_engine(
        conn,
        connect_args={'options': '-c statement_timeout=30000'})
```